# MediaWiki code - using ifexpr resulting in result repeating 4 times

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-templates

I'm working on a wiki but have no experience with MediaWiki language...the below code is used basically to provide an item label, but on the website that label is now repeated 3 additional times. I only want the label to appear once.

```
<data source="type">
    <label>Type</label>
    <format>{{#ifexpr:{{#rpos:{{lc:{{{type|}}}}}|weapon}}>=0|{{{type|}}}{{AddCategory|Weapon}}|{{{type|}}}}}<!--
         -->{{#ifexpr:{{#rpos:{{lc:{{{type|}}}}}|armor}}>=0|{{{type|}}}{{AddCategory|Armor}}|{{{type|}}}}}<!--
         -->{{#ifexpr:{{#rpos:{{lc:{{{type|}}}}}|palace}}>=0|{{{type|}}}{{AddCategory|Palace}}|{{{type|}}}}}<!--
         -->{{#ifexpr:{{#rpos:{{lc:{{{type|}}}}}|domain}}>=0|{{{type|}}}{{AddCategory|Domain}}|{{{type|}}}}}
    </format>
  </data>
```

Right now, any label that appears in this section looks like this on the website

[image]

Any assistance in getting this to read 'Soul' is greatly appreciated!

I poked around a little but I'm not responsible for the coding aspects of this, so I didn't want to try anything without gathering information first.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you are placing the text there 4 times. You're basically saying "If type contains weapon, then print type and add to category. Otherwise, print type." and that for other things in place of "weapon", 4 times.

Why don't you do something like this:

```
<data source="type">
    <label>Type</label>
    <format>{{{type|}}}<!--
         Now add categories if needed
         -->{{#ifexpr:{{#rpos:{{lc:{{{type|}}}}}|weapon}}>=0|{{AddCategory|Weapon}}}}<!--
         -->{{#ifexpr:{{#rpos:{{lc:{{{type|}}}}}|armor}}>=0|{{AddCategory|Armor}}}}<!--
         -->{{#ifexpr:{{#rpos:{{lc:{{{type|}}}}}|palace}}>=0|{{AddCategory|Palace}}}}<!--
         -->{{#ifexpr:{{#rpos:{{lc:{{{type|}}}}}|domain}}>=0|{{AddCategory|Domain}}}}
    </format>
  </data>
```

Or even this:

```
<data source="type">
    <label>Type</label>
    <format>{{{type|}}}</format>
  </data><!--

rest of page

Add categories at bottom of page:
-->{{#ifexpr:{{#rpos:{{lc:{{{type|}}}}}|weapon}}>=0|{{AddCategory|Weapon}}}}<!--
-->{{#ifexpr:{{#rpos:{{lc:{{{type|}}}}}|armor}}>=0|{{AddCategory|Armor}}}}<!--
-->{{#ifexpr:{{#rpos:{{lc:{{{type|}}}}}|palace}}>=0|{{AddCategory|Palace}}}}<!--
-->{{#ifexpr:{{#rpos:{{lc:{{{type|}}}}}|domain}}>=0|{{AddCategory|Domain}}}}
```

Hope this helps!